# Filter won't take in integers? Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I'm working on the Yelp Dataset using Spark Dataframe. I'm having issues with using filter().

It seems I cannot specify integers, only strings?

Here's my code

```
def fiveStarBusinessesDF(yelpBusinesses: DataFrame):DataFrame = {
    yelpBusinesses.select("name", "stars", "review_count").filter("stars" == 5, "review_count" >= 1000)
  }
```

Here's one row from the yelp dataset:

```
{"business_id":"1SWheh84yJXfytovILXOAQ","name":"Arizona Biltmore Golf Club","address":"2818 E Camino Acequia Drive","city":"Phoenix","state":"AZ","postal_code":"85016","latitude":33.5221425,"longitude":-112.0184807,"stars":3.0,"review_count":5,"is_open":0,"attributes":{"GoodForKids":"False"},"categories":"Golf, Active Life","hours":null}
```

Clearly the stars and review_count are both integers, and not strings.

The output of my function should be a DataFrame with the names, stars and review_count of all business with 5 stars, and more than or equal to a 1000 review_count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
    import spark.implicits._
    def fiveStarBusinessesDF(yelpBusinesses: DataFrame):DataFrame = {
       yelpBusinesses.select("name", "stars", "review_count")
                   .filter($"stars" === 5 && $"review_count" >= 1000)
    }
```

Comment: This one actually worked. But it isn't far off from mine. What does the "$" do? I've seen different uses of them.

Comment: This is a implicit representation of a column in Spark. You could also use col("stars") instead. Scala also uses the '$' sign for String interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

try cast to int

```
    import spark.implicits._
    def fiveStarBusinessesDF(yelpBusinesses: DataFrame):DataFrame = {
        yelpBusinesses.select('name, 'stars, 'review_count)
                      .filter('stars.cast("int") === 5 || 'review_count.cast("int") >= 1000)
      }
```

Comment: gives me an error underneath filter "Cannot resolve overloaded method filter()"

Comment: I don't know what spark version you are using, but as far as I know you can't put two conditions in the filter without using || or &&.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
def fiveStarBusinessesDF(yelpBusinesses: DataFrame):DataFrame = {
    yelpBusinesses.select("name", "stars", "review_count")
                  .filter("$stars" == 5 && "$review_count" >= 1000)
  }
```

or like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def fiveStarBusinessesDF(yelpBusinesses: DataFrame):DataFrame = {
        yelpBusinesses.select("name", "stars", "review_count")
                      .filter(col("stars") == lit(5) && col("review_count") >= lit(1000))
      }
```